# How does this code section print 5?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout<<(int *)16 -  (int *)10 ;
return 0;
}
```

This code section produces an output 5, i could not understand the output?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for the adobe tag?

Comment: Mine rounds off the difference to the nearest sizeof(int*) which is 4.

Comment: Mine says 1, which is same as `std::distance((int *)10, (int *)16)`, but that is C++14(or close to).

Comment: @Surt, `std::distance` has been there since the first standard. That doesn't change that this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why do you want to know? _Please_ tell me this code didn't come from a learning resource or teacher??

Comment: What does this have to do with hexadecimal?  Your posted code is using decimal.  Please remove the `hex` tag.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: inb4 "i thought all memory addresses are hex"

Comment: At the lowest level, all addresses are in binary, one address line per bit.  Their numeric base (representation) can be almost anything.  If the OP is using hex, then the expression would be `((int *) 0x10) - ((int *) 0x0A)`,  but none of the code is about hexadecimal arithmetic.  Addresses are commonly represented in hex to humans (that is, their *textual* representation).  Their internal representation is left to the processor and compiler.

Comment: Print the assembly language output of the program; the truth is in the assembly language.

Comment: Also, which compiler are you using?  What are the optimization settings?  What platform (OS & processor) are you using?  The behavior is processor dependent so all this information matters.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Yes, I'm aware. I think you misinterpreted my comment.

Answer (score 5):

There is no point in rationalising about this: you do not have an array that contains elements who live at `10` and `16` in memory. Therefore, the subtraction operation is undefined and anything can happen.

Speaking practically, since the difference between the two addresses is [probably] not a multiple of `sizeof(int)`, your compiler appears to be chickening out and returning abject nonsense.

Fortunately, you never have a reason to write this code in your projects, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: If his `int` was an `int16_t` then it should have returned 3? as he theoretically could have had an array there.

Comment: @Surt: He theoretically could have, but actually doesn't.

Comment: @Surt:  Alignment does not enter the picture when converting a number to an address.  The *type* field with pointers is used when incrementing or decrementing by a scalar quantity.  Alignment only occurs when allocating variables.

Comment: If you think the arithmetic difference between 10 and 16 is 5, then your primary school failed you :)